# Styling Combobox Dropdown to display on black background

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I am trying to style a QCombobox in the QT Designer, but for the life of me I cannot get this issue to stop happening.

[image]

I have the ui set to have a black background, and I can't seem to style the ComboBox so that when I click the arrow for the drop-down I can actually SEE the list of items beside the highlighted one. Currently every item in the list has a black background, and the text is also black, so you can't see anything.

I've tried all of the options in the QT Designer and nothing is helping. I've also Googled it to death and can't seem to just find a straightforward way to write the Stylesheet for that particular field/element's background color. I just want white cells with black text, pretty simple, really.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out.

```css
QWidget{
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Apparently I had to surround the surface styling with QWidget or it wouldn't recognize it. Which wasn't very clear to me. And no one else seems to ever have a simple, short, sweet problem like this. I hope some poor soul roaming Google finds this and feels relief that they could actually find someone with their problem.